# How to go back to a break point during debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, breakpoints

I am working in asp.net and debugging an application.

Sometimes there are scenarios in which I need to go back to a break point that I have passed. Is there any way to go back to that break point? I am debugging using F5 and F10 and press SHIFT+F5 to stop debugging.

I searched on google, but not finding the required answer.

Please guide me regarding this. I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At least in Visual Studio 2010 you can drag the yellow arrow showing your current line you're debugging. It doesn't work all the times though.

I've used that if I had accidently passed a function I should have debugged.

Comment: Ohh yes, that's working. Is there any shortcut to it? And why it does not always work?

Comment: I haven't found any shortcut, but I'm only using it for a short "jumps" so it's not that bad to drag it by hand. I think the reason why it doesn't always work is that the debugger can't roll back the changes. An extreme example could be that you're trying to reset to one point that you passed five minutes ago. Sounds pretty hard to me. But as I said, I'm not sure about the reason.

Comment: Shortcut (sort of) is to right click and Set Next Statement. Here it shows control-shift-F10 as a shortcut. ***Warning*** if you move the execution back, then state changing operations will be run again, this can – of course – easily lead to problems of its own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have VS 2010 Ultimate IntelliTrace, by default, records breakpoint state. You can go back an examine the state at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

you can drag the yellow arrow which line u want debugging .